# NativeScript - display element centered on tap

Tags: css, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a problem with the css with **NativeScript**.

(The solution for a normal webapp is: *translate(-50%, -50%)* but this isn't working for Nativescript)

**What I want:** A circle centered where I touch.

**What I get now:** A circle NOT centered where I touch.

Do you have an Idea?

(When I have only one Circle of 300px, I can cheat with "translate(-40%, -40%)" but I'm looking for a solution for XXXpx)

=====

**ANSWER**: given by theOriginalJosh

I have to remove in my css:

- the "px"

And in my Script:

- Soustract by 50% of the width and height the top and left properties.

====

*the Html*

```
<AbsoluteLayout #container>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

*The component*

```
@ViewChild('container') absoluteLayout: ElementRef;

public onTap(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
    if (args && args.action === 'down') {
        let xCoord = args.getX();
        let yCoord = args.getY();

        let label3 = new Label();
        label3.top = yCoord;
        label3.left = xCoord;
        label3.className = "circle three";

        let label4 = new Label();
        label4.top = yCoord;
        label4.left = xCoord;
        label4.className = "circle four";


        this.absoluteLayout.nativeElement.addChild(label3);
        this.absoluteLayout.nativeElement.addChild(label4);
    }
}
```

the css

```
.circle {
    color: blue ;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
.three {
    border-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-width: 20px;
} 
.four {
    border-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the height and width of the circles you are placing on the page you can subtract half of those circles height and widths from the X and Y coordinates. that should center them.

```
public onTap(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
    if (args && args.action === 'down') {
    let xCoord = args.getX();
    let yCoord = args.getY();

    let label3 = new Label();
    label3.top = yCoord - 25;
    label3.left = xCoord - 25;
    label3.className = "circle three";

    let label4 = new Label();
    label4.top = yCoord - 150;
    label4.left = xCoord - 150;
    label4.className = "circle four";


    this.absoluteLayout.nativeElement.addChild(label3);
    this.absoluteLayout.nativeElement.addChild(label4);
}
```

}

you may want to check out the nativescript-ng2-windchimes app on Github it's about a year old but has many of the concepts you're trying to do. https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ng2-windchimes

Comment: I have tried already like this but this is not at all centered. I don't know if the "pixel" of css are the same than the given coordinate.

Comment: maybe change the width and height css properties so they are not `px`?  and instead just '300` and `50`. px support was recently in N 3.0 I believe and I've never really used them in css styling.

Comment: Awesome! I'm sure there is a way to do it with px. maybe setting the transformY and transformX properties on the labels in code?